# Spring boot build without starting up the application

Tags: spring-boot

I want to build the spring boot jar file using maven like

```
mvn -B clean install -Pdev -DskipTests
```

But I do not want to start the spring boot app while doing this process as it cannot connect to the database from this build machine. How can I do that? Now the build is failing as it is trying to start up the server during the build process